# Check if the first and last chars of the string are the same in PHP

Tags: php

I want to check if first and last chars are the same. I tried this code:

```php
function myFunction(string $s): string {
  return $s[0]!=$s[-1]?"No":"Yes";
}
```

It works fine by using an online interpreter (repl.it), which is using PHP 7.0.8, but in my machine with PHP 7 I got this error:

> Uninitialized string offset: -1

Comment: Negative indexes are supported since `php7.1` Create a workaround.

Comment: thanks, this is what I guessed. it is supported on 7.0.8 (as I said), so it should be before that, not 7.1

Comment: A regex like `^(.).*\1$` would do it, or `substr($string, 0, 1) == substr($string, -1, 1);`

Comment: In repl.it you can run `echo PHP_VERSION;`. You will be surprised.

Comment: @u_mulder, you were right, it is 7.1.6 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php ***older version*** you can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$string = "abcda";

function myFunction($string){
  $string_array = str_split($string);
  return ($string_array[0]!=end($string_array))? "No":"Yes";
}

echo myFunction($string);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/839485   ***OR***  https://eval.in/839480

***From php 7.1 version onward*** you can use negative indexes like below:-

```
<?php

$string = "abcda";

function myFunction(string $s): string {
  return $s[0] != substr($s, -1) ? "No":"Yes";
}

echo myFunction($string);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/839477

Comment: I thought `substr($s, -1)` was avaliable in versions prior to 7.1.

Comment: Why not end()? `return ($string_array[0]!=end($string_array))? "No":"Yes";`

Comment: thanks, end function, and $s[0] != $s[-1]    are working fine on php 7.1 onward.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan  and andreas i changed that one.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative indexes from PHP 7.1 : https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative-string-offsets

Just use other method :

```
function myFunction(string $s): string {
  return $s[0] != substr($s, -1) ? "No":"Yes";
}
```